# Different interpretations of point mass (degenerate distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a Probability book by Karr, the point mass (degenerate distribution) is defined as:

The *point mass* (degenerate distribution) at (a fixed point) $\omega\in\Omega$:
$\epsilon_{\omega}(A)$ = $1_A(\omega)$ (where $1$ is the indicator function).

Since the LHS is a function of A (for a fixed outcome $\omega$), and the RHS is a function of $\omega$ (for a fixed event A), how can the two functions be equal? What does the equality here represents?

Is it ok if I interpret it as $\mathbb{P}(A) = \epsilon_{\omega}(A)$? If yes, why, if no why not?

I might care too much about unnecessary details, but any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $\omega$ in $\Omega$, the functions $\epsilon_\omega$ and $\mathbf 1_{\cdot}(\omega)$ are both defined on $2^\Omega$ the set of subsets of $\Omega$.

For each $A\subseteq\Omega$, the functions $\epsilon_{\cdot}(A)$ and $\mathbf 1_A$ are both defined on $\Omega$.

The assertion is that the two functions $u$ and $v$ defined on $\Omega\times2^\Omega$ by $u(\omega,A)=\epsilon_\omega(A)$ and $v(\omega,A)=\mathbf 1_A(\omega)$ for every $(\omega,A)$ in $\Omega\times2^\Omega$ coincide.

> Is it ok if I interpret it as $\mathbb{P}(A) = \epsilon_{\omega}(A)$?

Not at all, since $\mathbb{P}(A)$ depends on $A\subseteq\Omega$ while $\epsilon_{\omega}(A)$ depends on $\omega$ in $\Omega$ and on $A\subseteq\Omega$. In fact,
$$
\mathbb{P}(A) =\int_\Omega \epsilon_{\omega}(A)\mathbb P(\mathrm d\omega).
$$

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was very helpful.