# A probability measure that takes only the values 0 and 1 but not a point mass

Tags: measure-theory

Exactly the same question as here: [A probability measure that takes only the values $0$ and $1$ but is not a point mass](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454512/a-probability-measure-that-takes-only-the-values-0-and-1-but-is-not-a-point#1454512)

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, and let $\mathcal{F}=\sigma \left(\{1,2,3,4\},\{3,4,5,6\}\right).$

Can we show that there exists a probability $P$ on $\Omega$ such that $P(A)$ is zero or one for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$, yet $P$ is not a point mass?

In [A probability measure that takes only the values $0$ and $1$ but is not a point mass](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454512/a-probability-measure-that-takes-only-the-values-0-and-1-but-is-not-a-point#1454512), it is explained that it can be solved using the fact that the $\sigma$-algebra cannot differentiate between 1 and 2, but I still do not get it.

Comment: "Exactly the same question": so why don't you just read the answer there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A probability measure that takes only the values $0$ and $1$ but is not a point mass](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454512/a-probability-measure-that-takes-only-the-values-0-and-1-but-is-not-a-point)

Comment: It might not be an exact duplicate. It looks like Sheldon tried to edit the linked post to ask the question he's answering here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A probability measure on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is a function
$\mu\colon \mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$ satisfying the axioms of a measure, and such that $\mu(\Omega)=1$.

Here, you have 
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{F} &= \sigma(\{1,2,3,4\},\{3,4,5,6\})\\
&= \{\emptyset,\Omega,\{1,2,3,4\},\{3,4,5,6\},
\{5,6\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,5,6\}, \{3,4\}\}
\end{align}$$
the last equality using the [definition of a generated $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra#.CF.83-algebras_generated_by_families_of_sets). *(I think I did not miss any.)*

Therefore, to define your probability measure $\mu$ you only need to assign (consistent) values to the sets of $\mathcal{F}$. You can see that in this case, one can define $\mu$ by 
$$
\mu(\{1,2\})=1
$$
and the value assigned to the other sets following from properties of a measure:
\begin{align}
\mu(\emptyset) &= 0\\
\mu(\Omega) &= 1\\
\mu(\{1,2,3,4\} )&= 1\\
\mu(\{3,4,5,6\} )&= 0\\
\mu(\{5,6\})&=0\\
\mu(\{1,2\})&=1\\
\mu(\{1,2,5,6\})&=1\\
\mu(\{3,4\})&=0
\end{align}

This fully defines $\mu$, yet one can see $\mu$ is not a "point mass." It does not put probability mass $1$ on any singleton, *as there is no singleton in the $\sigma$-algebra with mass $1$*. (Nor any singleton, for that matter.)

In particular, indeed $\mu$ "does not differentiate between $1$ and $2$": both points are always together in any event they belong to, and neither of them has a separate well-defined probability mass. $\{1,2\}$ is an event with probability mass $1$, but neither $\{1\}$ nor $\{2\}$ is an event.

Comment: Mmh: would [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380232/different-interpretations-of-point-mass-degenerate-distribution) be enough?

Comment: I was confused at the Karr's definition about point mass too. Now it has taken care of my two concerns simultaneously! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Let $P: \mathcal{F} \to [0,1]$ be defined by $P(A) = \sum_{\omega \in A}p(\omega)$, where $p: \Omega: \to [0,1]$ is given by $p(1)=p(2) = 1/2$ and $p(\omega) = 0$ for every other $\omega \in \Omega$.

It's easy to check that $P$ takes values in $\{ 0,1 \}$. But $P$ is not a point mass because there is no $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $P(\{ \omega \})=1$. (In fact, there are no singleton events in $\mathcal{F}$.)

Comment: @Sheldon I edited to make more explicit what I have in mind. This is the standard way of defining probability measures on discrete spaces. Note that $P$ takes values in $\{ 0,1 \}$ because $\mathcal{F}$ does not contain any singleton sets.

Comment: I think I got most of what you said. But I am still wondering how is this $P(A)$ different from a point mass. I guess I am stuck with the feeling that $P$ is point mass if $P(A)$ is either 0 or 1, which is the case here. Thanks!

Comment: @Sheldon If that's your definition of a point mass, then how could your question have an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Any principle ultrafilter $\mu_S$ on this set is an example, where $S$ is not a singleton. For example, let $S = \{ 1,2 ,3\},$ and let $\mu_S(X) = 1 \iff X \supset S$, and otherwise $\mu_S(X) = 0$. Then clearly this measure is not a point-mass, but it also takes only those two values.